# Context manager for optionally redirected I/O

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm often faced with the situation that depending on some command line argument, input might either come from a file or standard input. The same goes for output. I really like how context managers in python 3 work, and therefore try to make all my `open` calls part of some `with` statement. But in this case, I'm having trouble.

```
if args.infile:
    with open(args.infile, "r") as f:
        process(f)
else:
    process(sys.stdin)
```

is already clumsy, and with both input and output I'd have to cater for four combinations. I would like something easier, e.g.

```
with (open(args.infile, "r") if args.infile
      else DummyManager(sys.stdin)) as f:
    process(f)
```

Is there something like this DummyManager in the python standard libraries? Something which implements the context manager protocol, but only to return a fixed value from its `__enter__` method? I guess the most likely location for such a class would be [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html), and since I didn't find anything like this there, perhaps there is no such thing. Are there other elegant solutions you can suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you could use [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):

```
from fileinput import FileInput

with FileInput(args.infile) as file:
    process(file)
# sys.stdin is still open here
```

If `args.infile='-'` then it uses `sys.stdin`. If `inplace=True` parameter then it redirects `sys.stdout` to the input file. You could pass several filenames. If there are no filenames it uses filenames given at the command-line or stdin.

Or you could leave the file as is:

```
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--log', default=sys.stdout, type=argparse.FileType('w'))
args = parser.parse_args()
with args.log:
    args.log.write('log message')
# sys.stdout may be closed here
```

It should be fine for most programs where stdout may be used to write the result.

To avoid closing `sys.stdin / sys.stdout`, you could use [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to enable the context managers conditionally:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    if not args.files:
       files = [sys.stdin]
    else:
       files = [stack.enter_context(open(name)) for name in args.files]

    if not args.output:
       output_file = sys.stdout
       stack.callback(output_file.flush) # flush instead of closing 
    else:
       output_file = stack.enter_context(open(args.output, 'w'))

    process(files, output_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to create one with the [`@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def dummy_manager(ob):
    yield ob
```

That's it; this creates a context manager that does nothing but hand you `ob` back, and the `__exit__` handler does exactly nothing.

I'd use it like this:

```
f = open(args.infile, "r") if args.infile else dummy_manager(sys.stdin)
with f:
    process(f)
```

Comment: This works with Python 2.7—`FileInput()` didn't gain context manager support until 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dummy manager in your case.  `sys.stdin`, being file-like, can be used as a context manager.

```
with (open(args.infile, "r") if args.infile else sys.stdin) as f:
    process(f)
```

One thing to note is that when `__exit__`ing the block, sys.stdin gets `close`d (while you ordinarily don't need/want to close it yourself), but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Various `ArgParse` wrappers and replacements now exist which support this nicely.  I like [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/):

```
with click.open_file(filename) as lines:
    for line in lines:
        process(line)
```

This will handle `sys.stdin` if `filename` is `-` and otherwise fall back to the regular `open` with a `close` hidden in the context manager's `finally` part.